# String Comparison with Elasticsearch Groovy Dynamic Script

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index that contains various member documents. Each member document contains a membership object, along with various fields associated with / describing individual membership. For example:

```
{membership:{'join_date':2015-01-01,'status':'A'}}
```

Membership status can be 'A' (active) or 'I' (inactive); both Unicode string values. I'm interested in providing a slight boost the score of documents that contain active membership status.

In my groovy script, along with other custom boosters on various numeric fields, I have added the following:

```
String status = doc['membership.status'].value; 
float status_boost = 0.0;

if (status=='A') {status_boost = 2.0} else {status_boost=0.0}; 

return _score + status_boost
```

For some reason associated with how strings operate via groovy, the check `(status=='A')` does not work. I've attempted `(status.toString()=='A')`, `(status.toString()=="A")`, `(status.equals('A'))`, plus a number of other variations.

How should I go about troubleshooting this (in a productive, efficient manner)? I don't have a stand-alone installation of groovy, but when I pull the response data in python the status is very much so either a Unicode 'A' or 'I' with no additional spacing or characters.

Comment: Are you sure the value is 'A' , because due to analyzing this might have been changed to small ;a' .Can you try with that.

Comment: You were absolutely correct - thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@VineetMohan is most likely right about the value being `'a'` rather than `'A'`.

You can check how the values are indexed by spitting them back out as script fields:

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/_search -d '
{
  "script_fields": {
    "status": {
      "script": "doc[\"membership.status\"].values"
    }
  }
}
'
```

From there, it should be an indication of what you're actually working with. More than likely based on the name and your usage, [you will want to reindex (recreate) your data so that `membership.status` is mapped as a `not_analyzed` string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2). If done, then you won't need to worry about lowercasing of anything.

In the mean time, you can probably get by with:

```
return _score + (doc['membership.status'].value == 'a' ? 2 : 0)
```

As a big aside, you should not be using dynamic scripting. Use stored scripts in production to avoid security issues.

Comment: By checking the value via script_fields instead of the value stored in the _source document, I found that not only was the 'A' lowercased, but it was also wrapped in brackets. The former makes perfect sense, but I find the latter a bit strange (given that the value is mapped as a string). Setting s = doc['membership.status'].value[0], then checking s against "a" did the trick.

Comment: The bracketed nature of it is largely to do with the fact that I used `values` instead of `value` in the output, as well as just how `script_fields` displays content. Don't worry too much about that unless it was also returning more than one value, which _analyzed_ strings are prone to do.